# Change ginput crosshair appearance - Matlab

Tags: matlab

How can I change the cross-hair to a circle with the same r (20)?

Code:

```
clc;
clear;
I = imread('peppers.png');
imshow(I); 
colorCode = [0.6 0.8 0.5] *255;

r=20;
button = 1;
 while sum(button) <=1    
    [x,y,button] = ginput(1)
    I= insertShape(I,'FilledCircle',[x y r],'LineWidth',1, 'Color', colorCode,  'Opacity', 1);
    imshow(I); 
 end
```

Comment: You'll have to write your own version of `ginput`. It's not as difficult as it looks.

Comment: Any tip how to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am using Matlab R2015b and I do not know if `ginput` has been modified since then. 
In the particular version that I have, `ginput` has its crosshair code mainly in two functions:

```
function updateCrossHair(fig, crossHair)
% update cross hair for figure.
gap = 3; % 3 pixel view port between the crosshairs
cp = hgconvertunits(fig, [fig.CurrentPoint 0 0], fig.Units, 'pixels', fig);
cp = cp(1:2);
figPos = hgconvertunits(fig, fig.Position, fig.Units, 'pixels', fig.Parent);
figWidth = figPos(3);
figHeight = figPos(4);

% Early return if point is outside the figure
if cp(1) < gap || cp(2) < gap || cp(1)>figWidth-gap || cp(2)>figHeight-gap
    return
end

set(crossHair, 'Visible', 'on');
thickness = 1; % 1 Pixel thin lines. 
set(crossHair(1), 'Position', [0 cp(2) cp(1)-gap thickness]);
set(crossHair(2), 'Position', [cp(1)+gap cp(2) figWidth-cp(1)-gap thickness]);
set(crossHair(3), 'Position', [cp(1) 0 thickness cp(2)-gap]);
set(crossHair(4), 'Position', [cp(1) cp(2)+gap thickness figHeight-cp(2)-gap]);
end


function crossHair = createCrossHair(fig)
% Create thin uicontrols with black backgrounds to simulate fullcrosshair pointer.
% 1: horizontal left, 2: horizontal right, 3: vertical bottom, 4: vertical top
for k = 1:4
    crossHair(k) = uicontrol(fig, 'Style', 'text',...
                             'Visible', 'off',...
                             'Units', 'pixels',...
                             'BackgroundColor', [1 0 0],...
                             'HandleVisibility', 'off',...
                             'HitTest', 'off'); %#ok<AGROW>
end

end
```

It is interesting to see that

1. People are working around the limit of drawing functions such as [`insertShape`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/ref/insertshape.html) found in a toolbox, which is the fact that the circle is burnt into the image and there is no easy way to "move" it.
2. An undocumented function `hgconvertunits` is used to ensure the units are of desired type.

What I have found that can move is [`annotation`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/annotation.html). 
Here is some example code that moves the ellipse following the mouse pointer. 
Since `ginput` is not editable, I copied all content into a function, and changed the call to `ginput` to the new function instead. 
Below is the modification to `ginput`.

```
function updateCrossHair(fig, crossHair)
% update cross hair for figure.
% get current point and positions; take care of units
cp = hgconvertunits(fig, [fig.CurrentPoint 0 0], fig.Units, 'pixels', fig);
figPos = hgconvertunits(fig, fig.Position, fig.Units, 'pixels', fig.Parent);
cp = cp(1:2)./figPos(3:4);
axesPos = fig.Children.Position;
% Early return if point is outside the figure
if cp(1) < axesPos(1) || cp(2) < axesPos(2) || cp(1) > (axesPos(1)+axesPos(3)) || cp(2) > axesPos(2)+axesPos(4)
    return
end

diameter = 10; % pixels
crossHair.Position = [cp-diameter./figPos(3:4)/2, diameter./figPos(3:4)];

end


function crossHair = createCrossHair(fig)
crossHair = annotation(fig, 'ellipse', [0,0,0,0]);
crossHair.Color = 'w';
end
```

There is a potential bug in this method, that is in the end of user input, when `enter` key is hit, the modified function does not return any `x` or `y` value. 
In fact the function outputs in the while loop are empty matrices.

To avoid crashing, simply add a check after user input, like this:

```
 while sum(button) <=1    
    [x,y,button] = testf(1) % use modified ginput
    if isempty(x) || isempty(y)
        break
    end
    I= insertShape(I,'FilledCircle',[x y r],'LineWidth',1, 'Color', colorCode,  'Opacity', 1);
    imshow(I); 
 end
```

Comment: Will find a way to make the crosshair size be consistent with circles to draw on the image, when I find time.